# iPad Simulator does not launch application

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios-simulator, xcode11

If I start my app on any iPad, my app does not run. It just shows a white screen and nothing happens.

The app runs perfectly fine on an iPhone simulator.

I tried closing/opening Xcode and erasing all simulators, but nothing seem to work.

**Im on Xcode 11 stable release**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a SwiftUI application, then by default, the navigation style is set to Double Columns.

It consists of a Master View and a Detail View, side by side.

If you try running it in simulator in landscape mode, you will see your view on the left

I will assume that you only have the Master View. 
So add the modifiier `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` AFTER the closing brace of Navigation View.

```
NavigationView {
    ...
}
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```